# Reduce the size of an existing VolumeGroup to create a new PhysicalVolume

Tags: linux, centos, partition, lvm, fdisk

I have test machine that is set up with default partition settings for CentOS 6.

```
[root@base_machine ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      7.5G  936M  6.3G  15% /
tmpfs                 246M     0  246M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   57M  395M  13% /boot
```

Initially, this was how the LV was set up:

```
[root@base_machine ~]# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                VolGroup
  LV UUID                irl20b-p6jE-y7Vi-3QlF-fVGf-zhr5-2SrU0K
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-09-10 20:51:26 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                6.71 GiB
  Current LE             1718
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
  LV Name                lv_swap
  VG Name                VolGroup
  LV UUID                DBDWBm-SjBB-OtDa-wRFC-uBTc-kWE8-j2De1R
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2015-09-10 20:51:28 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                816.00 MiB
  Current LE             204
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

I freed up some space using `lvresize`, like so:

```
[root@base_machine ~]# lvresize -L -1024M /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
  WARNING: Reducing active and open logical volume to 5.71 GiB
  THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to reduce lv_root? [y/n]: y
  Size of logical volume VolGroup/lv_root changed from 6.71 GiB (1718 extents) to 5.71 GiB (1462 extents).
  Logical volume lv_root successfully resized
```

Hence, there's now 1GB of Free Size in the VolumeGroup:

```
root@base_machine ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               7.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1922
  Alloc PE / Size       1666 / 6.51 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       256 / 1.00 GiB
  VG UUID               BRzfQl-CIJO-YYno-y9dj-TLnY-NLeb-paN9N7
```

How would I now go about freeing up the said 1 GB to create a new PV? The aim is to create a new partition, like **/dev/sdb**, or something similar - this is for testing out disk-resizing/LVM etc.

Comment: I don't understand, what's stopping you from creating a new lv? That 1GB is already "free", you just need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 6.51G /dev/sda1`.
I am pretty sure, this won't work because it's likely that `lv_swap` is allocated behind the 6.51G border.

So I think you should remove and recreate `lv_swap` as well:

```
swapoff /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
lvremove /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 6G /dev/sda2
```

Then resize the partition to around 6.5G (or slightly bigger). After that you should run a `pvresize /dev/sda2` to reclaim the space produced by the "slightly bigger". Then you can recreate `lv_swap`:

```
lvcreate -n lv_swap -l 100%FREE VolGroup
mkswap /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
swapon /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap
```